# Logging to console shows defined value, but using property errors out as undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angular, http

I am trying to debug a TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

I set up console logging to log the values, and they are defined when I console.log them, but they are undefined when I try to use them to create my Place object below.

Is .name special?

```
doSearch(term: string) {
this.searchService.onSearchClick(term).subscribe((data) => {
  this.searchResults = [];
  console.log(data); //works
  if (data.hasOwnProperty('candidates')) {
    data['candidates'].forEach( (place) => {
      console.log(place); //works
      console.log(place.formatted_address); //works
      console.log(place.name); //works 
      console.log(place.place_id); //works
      this.searchResults.push(new Place(place.formatted_address,
        '',
        '',
        '',
        new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(0, 0),
        place.name,
        new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(0, 0),
        [],
        place.place_id, //errors out here...
        99,
        99,
        new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(0, 0),
        '',
        '',
        '',
        []));
    });
  }
});
```

I am expecting that place.name is defined, because the console log is showing it is, but I get an undefined error.

The code above logs out:

The object,
The array,
the arrayobject formatted_address,
the arrayobject name,
the arrayobject place_id

All are defined and present when I console.log.

But it errors out on the place.name when I am trying to create a Place object.

Comment: Are you sure that the error occurs in that method? You can check that with a `console.log` statement at the end of the method. Maybe you refer to a `name` property somewhere else in the code or in the component template.

Comment: Wow. Yeah you were completely correct. The error was later in the html when it was trying render. Thank you for putting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to ConnorsFan for putting me in the right direction.

The error was happening later when the html was trying to render a component. The place object was created successfully. I just assumed it was erroring out in the wrong location in the code. I should really read the line numbers that the console provides to save myself a headache next time...